# Serverless Cron Syntax For Scheduled Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, cron, amazon-cloudwatch, serverless-framework

How can I write the cron syntax to schedule a Lambda to run every ten minutes at the start of every hour? Here is what I've tried but keep running into errors:

```
users-cron:
  handler: functions/users.cron
  events:
    - schedule:
        rate: rate(10 minutes)
    - schedule:
        rate: cron(0-10 0-23 ? * MON-SUN *)
```

Answer (score 2):

Form [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/tutorial-scheduled-events-schedule-expressions.html), there is a very similar example:

> Invoke a Lambda function every 10 min Mon-Fri
>   `cron(0/10 * ? * MON-FRI *)`

You could try:

```
users-cron:
  handler: functions/users.cron
  events:
    - schedule:
        rate: cron(0/10 * ? * * *)
```

Comment: Do you understand the difference between the question mark, ?, and the asterisk, *? For instance why not replace the ,?, with an asterisk? Will it not behave the same way? If not, how will the scheduled job behave differently?

Comment: From the same link: `* - Specifies All values`, `? - No specified value` and `One of the day-of-month or day-of-week values must be a question mark (?).`

Answer (score 1):

This is the exact syntax that answers my question:

```
users-cron:
  handler: functions/users.cron
  events:
    - schedule:
        rate: cron(0/10 0-23 ? * MON-SUN *)
```

Comment: Why don't you remove the first schedule? It seems that, if you keep the `rate: rate(10 minutes)`, your function will execute two times. The difference is that this 10 minutes execution will start when the function is deployed and not at the start of the hour.

Comment: Also, using `0-23` or `*` for hour and `MON-SUN` or `*` for day-of-week are equivalent syntax. The asterisk means `Specifies All values`.

Comment: you are right! sorry that was a type. I removed, `rate: rate(10 minutes)`